# How can "lebensphasenorientierte Personalpolitik" be translated to English?

Tags: terminology, translation, german

In German, "lebensphasenorientierte Personalpolitik" describes a human resource policy that adapts to the life stages of employees, and enables a work-life balance.

Is there an equivalent English technical term for this?

The literal translation "Life stage oriented human resource policy" does not seem to be the proper term.

Comment: Work-life balance?

Comment: The United Nations Economic Commission for Europe uses the phrases "age-friendly employment" and  "age-friendly conditions in the workplace".

Comment: Note that this concept is largely unknown in the US.

Comment: A 'human resource policy that adapts to the life stages of employees, and enables a work-life balance' sounds like a fine translation. There's less glue in English, though someone will perhaps come up with a snappy acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to a shorter phrase, I would make the following suggestion:

> Employee-oriented personnel policy

I think `Emplyoee` can stand in for: `stage in life of the eployee`. The crux here is the word `life` you don't need to have it explicit and force the translation. Your initial german phrase needs to be adapted so that it conveys the same `core idea` but for an english speaking audience, I think now it's something like this:

> Mitarbeiterorientierte Personalpolitik